# How do I get the functor signature selected by overload resolution?

Tags: c++

I want to grab the type of `operator()` of arbitrary types given its arguments.

```
template<typename F, typename... Args>
constexpr auto call_ptr =
    static_cast<std::invoke_result_t<F, Args...> (F::*)(Args...)>(&F::operator());
```

However, `call_ptr` doesn't work with overload resolution. For example, these all fail

```
struct S {
    void operator()(double) {}
    void operator()(int) {}
};
call_ptr<S, char>;

call_ptr<decltype([](auto&&){}), int>;
```

How do I write `call_ptr`?

Comment: @Jarod42 I can work around cv-qualified member functions by SFINAEing through all combinations. The problem is with the arguments.

Comment: @Jarod42 But that's the point, I want to get the signature selected by overload resolution. If I knew the signature before hand, I wouldn't have to get it.

Comment: Can't you use lambda instead? Something like: `call_ptr = [](auto&& f, Args... args){ return std::invoke(f, args...); }`

Comment: @Jarod42 No, I really need the type. There are two places where I need this. The first is creating a unique id for `operator()` across different classes, for which the type is needed. The second is type-erasing functors with signature `void(T)`, where I need to store something like `void(void*)` and cast the arguments back to `T`.

Comment: Not possible. Overload resolution is only performed in a context of an actual function call, and in that context the selected function pointer is not available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to do this, but there is a proposal to add this functionality into the language: http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n3866.html

Comment: Looks pretty grim that this is going to make it huh?